# Unable to log in: "Cannot serve directory www/wordpress/wp-includes/ No matching DirectoryIndex"

Tags: errors, 500-internal-error

I was trying to log into my Wordpress website. The main website is fine, but when I access http://[domain]/admin, I get:

- Firefox - a blank website
- Brave - In-browser error message "[domain] is currently unable to handle this request.
  HTTP ERROR 500"

Given that it's an internal error, I looked and found this in my error log:

```
[autoindex:error] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home/directory/www/wordpress/wp-includes/: No matching DirectoryIndex 

(index.html,index.htm,index.shtml,index.shtm,index.cgi,index.php,index.hdml) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

It looks like this is a theme-related issue, as indicated on [the Wordpress Forum](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/cant-access-wordpress-dashboard-critical-error/).

I'd like to disable all themes, if that would resolve this issue, but I'm not able to log in.

What other methods are there to resolve this?

Comment: This is most likely due to a server error. Perhaps you should contact your hosting provider.

Comment: Are you trying `{domain.com}/admin` or `{domain.com}/wp-admin`? The latter is the WordPress standard dashboard URL.

Comment: @PatJ I'm trying to access either of them and already tried both.

Comment: Looking at the error again, something's trying to load the `/wp-includes/` folder. That shouldn't be happening. I suspect you're going to need to either a) talk to your hosting provider or b) get hands-on help from someone.